# Post value into textbox using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to post the value into textbox, depending on the value of my other textbox. Just for i.e I input pencil in try1 field, the value should show in try2 field is A00003. I got it in alert message. But the problem is there's no value returning in textbox try2. What is the problem with this?

Any help will appreciate.

**Table Structure**

```
Item    |  Item_Code
Pencil  |  A00003  
Ballpen |  A00004
```

**index.php**

```
<input id="try1" name="try1">
<input id="try2" name="try2">
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('input[id="try1"]').change(function() 
{
var try1 = $("#try1").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getajax.php",
data :"try1="+try1,
dataType:'html',
type:'POST',
   success:function(data){
   alert(data)
    $('#try2').html(data);
   } 
  });
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

**GetAjax.php**

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "2015");
if(isset($_POST['try1']))
{
$try1 = $_POST['try1'];
$sql = $mysqli->query("select item_code from code where item='$try1'");

while($row1 = $sql->fetch_assoc())
  {
  $code = $row1['item_code'];
  }
echo $code;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

use `val()` for input element.

```
$('#try2').val(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

for writting a data into `input box` you need to use `val()` like this

```
$('#try2').val(data);
```

`html()` is generally used for writting `html contents` into `divs ,spans , etc`.

***Additional Info***: for writting data into a `label` you can use `text("data")`

Answer (score 0):

Assign **data** to *value*.

```
$('#try2').value =data;
```